# I want the returned data to be written to the div tag of the html

Tags: ajax, jquery

```
function showPrice(data) //pass the data as an object literal instead of a string
{
    var $remaining = $('#remaining');

    $remaining.empty();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'getevent.php',
        data: data,
        success: function(reponse){
            $remaining.html(reponse);
        }
    });
}

$('#events').change(function(){

    var pluspoint=$('#events').val();

    var data = { q : 1};

    showPrice(data);
});
```

I am trying to pass variable q to a php file and get back the result . I am getting the result but I am getting an error paramete q is undefined .

Comment: Where are you getting the error message from? Javascript or PHP?

Comment: I am not gettin an error message i want the rendered ajax output to be displayed in my source code

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON.stringify:

```
function showPrice(data) //pass the data as an object literal instead of a string
{
    var $remaining = $('#remaining');

    $remaining.empty();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'getevent.php',
        data: data,
        success: function(reponse){
            $remaining.html( JSON.stringify(reponse) );
        }
    });
}

$('#events').change(function(){

    var pluspoint=$('#events').val();

    var data = { q : 1};

    showPrice(data);
});
```

Comment: Nope , Still I am unable to see the added code between the div tags :( . No luck